# FlexCard: Embedded LWC not receiving attributes from Test Parameters

Tags: lightning-web-components, omnistudio

I have a LWC which I embed inside my flex card. The LWC has two @api parameters (caseid and userid). My LWC console.logs these variables in ConnectedCallback to show that they are being written.

In my Flexcard, I am setting two test parameters. One of these Parameters I am using successfully in my Data Source (DataRaptor)

[image]

If I hardcode a value into one of the parameters, the LWC will receive the value. However, if I pass a value that I'm setting in the Test Parameters, the variable is undefined.

[image: Attributes for embedded LWC being set]

I've tested the Test Parameter Merge fields in a Text Element in the FlexCard, and they are working fine. So why is it that I can't pass the Test Parameters to an embedded LWC?

NOTE: I've tried using one of the JSON nodes that are coming back from my DataSource, but it still doesn't work. Even though the node is working when being printed out in a Text Element, it won't work when I pass it as an attribute to the LWC

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this issue. Any luck?

Comment: Did you find the solution?
Facing same issue and not sure how to resolve.